# Como servir uma página estática a partir do urls.py?

Tags: django

Tenho um site em Django onde quero servir o `favicon.ico` - que sendo um arquivo estático, está em `STATIC_URL/caminho/pro/favicon.ico`. É possível fazer isso direto do `urls.py`? (i.e. sem ter que escrever uma *view* só pra isso)

Encontrei [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15706489/520779) que diz como mapear de um padrão pra outro [nomeado], mas não é isso que eu preciso: eu quero mapear de um padrão para uma URL estática. Algo como:

```python
url(r'^favicon.ico$', view_que_serve_a_partir_do_STATIC_ROOT_ou_redireciona_pro_STATIC_URL),
```

É possível? E se não, qual seria a alternativa menos trabalhosa?

P.S. Estou usando o Django 1.4.14, no Python 2.6.0 (e não, devido a restrições no meu ambiente não dá pra atualizar pra uma versão mais recente...)

Comment: Por que não usar `{% static 'path' %}` no template?

Comment: @Orion porque não tem template... É o próprio browser que requisita o `/favicon.ico`, independentemente do que tem na página (se bem que descobri recentemente que é possível especificar o favicon [através de uma tag no `head` da página](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6644684/520779), tornando esse requisito desnecessário)

Comment: Nem sabia que o browser requisitava sem indicar no `head` da página o endereço do ícone, por isso achei estranho não usar o `{% static 'path' %}`, mas está explicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com [uma resposta à mesma pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25910919/520779), esse tipo de coisa é melhor feita no webserver (Apache, nginx...) do que no Django. Entretanto, como um *workaround* há a possibilidade de se usar [uma *view* genérica](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects), por exemplo a `RedirectView`:

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

class FaviconView(RedirectView):
    url = "/static/favicon.ico"

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^favicon.ico$', FaviconView.as_view()),
```